# Archivo que genera error NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception

Hola yo no sé un pepino de programación, sin embargo el fisco nos obliga a los contadores a usar su programa "DIMM FORMULARIOS" para realizar declaraciones de impuestos. Hice la declaración en este programa y al querer subir el archivo que se genera en formato .XML (comprimido en .ZIP) me sale ese error. Hay como cambiar el error solo editando el XML? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! NO tenemos la más remota idea de cómo hicieron el programa que mencionas. Así pues, el fallo puede deberse a infinidad de motivos y es básicamente un problema que el programador no controló adecuadamente. Como usuario, puedes probar usar un archivo más pequeño. ¿Probaste ver qué sale al darle clic al botón `Ver Errores`? Y pues... como las preguntas acá son sobre programación y acá no hay programación por revisar, te comento que es posible que cierren la pregunta. En cualquier caso, reporta este problema al proveedor del programa para que lo revisen :)

Comment: PD. Si nos escribes desde Ecuador, recuerda que estos módulos los están reemplazando por el servicio en línea desde 2023 :)